# How to check if HTML video can't be played?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

All the answers available on the internet are in respect to knowing if video can be played. I have a different situation here, I need to know if video can't be played or video src is not accessible at all.

There are few events explained on this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp), but none is helpful to resolve my query.

I have also tried to execute `error` event as follows:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

vid.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error");
};
```

**Additional info:**
Video src could be from anywhere, any domain.

Comment: Not certain what issue is? Are you trying to determine if the `HTMLVideoElement` at the specific browser can play the MIME type of the media resource?

Comment: I'm trying to trigger an error if video doesn't exist, not accessible, can't be played by browser etc.

Answer (score 3):

Able to fix the situation with:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

vid.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    alert('error');
}, true);
```

`onerror` event is not valid for HTML video tags so far, but attaching an event with the help of event listener had solved my issue. I'm sharing my answer too as this might be helpful for someone else out there.

Comment: While this code probably does add an error handler, at least on firefox the callback doesn't get called when the video can't be played.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the attributes https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp for the video tag in html5 you can see wich attributes we need to use to trigger error from there :

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
alert(vid.error.code);
```

Comment: What is "crossdomain.xml"?

Comment: sorry mystake this is for audio/video shockwave flash, you need to setup you page header like the example, regards.

Comment: You may want to remove this CORS note since it is absolutely not needed to **play** a media, only to extract content from it.

Comment: CORS header is not necessary to play media at `<video>` element

Comment: @guest271314 it depend of how you have settings you restriction server.

Comment: @Kaiido if you want to seek and streaming some video from differents domain, playing a video src isn't a problem but if you use a server of streaming as RED5, WOWZA ... you needed it cos you need to post get with API rest ... I am talking about Live TV, Radio ... But ok in this context isn't needed.

Comment: But then the cross-origin error will raise in the POST request, not in the MediaElement's one.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't want to offenses your knowledge but look in the attributes video here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp you can see crossOrigin  Sets or returns the CORS settings of the audio/video there is more situation you need it but here a situation example : http://overengineer.net/enabling-cors-for-html5-video-element-screenshots

Comment: Well... my knowledge is not absolute, but in this case, it is not shaked at all. I absolutely don't trust w3School sources so I didn't even read their article, but what you say from it is what I said too, and the example you linked to is exactly my point: *[Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is only needed] to extract content from it, [not to play it]*. Yes drawing a video on a canvas and calling toDataURL on this canvas is one way to extract the media's content, there are multiple other ways, but none will block you from **playing** the media.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess we talk the same thing, and i remove the CORS for the reason you have exposed. But this talk clean the confuse about why CORS is needed in some particular situations and i guess the Topic want it for some reason. Nice too meet you ;). Regards.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fetch()` with `mode` set to `"no-cors"` to make a `HEAD` request to determine if the resource exists

```
fetch("/path/to/resource", {method:"HEAD", mode:"no-cors"})
.then(response => response.status)
.then(res => console.log(res))
// if we do not reach here, the resource should exist
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and use `HTMLVideoElement.prototype.canPlayType` to determine if the `<video>` element at the specific browser can play the media

```
video.canPlayType("video/webm")
```

Comment: Sure. I'll try this out. Thanks

Comment: That will just throw in case of cross-origin request, even if the MediaElement is able to read the content. Take for example `https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4` .

Comment: @Kaiido See updated post. Included `mode:"no-cors"` at `fetch()` options

Comment: @guest271314 unfortunately, 'no-cors' won't help here, it will not throw, but since the response will be opaque, you'll always get `false`.

Comment: @Kaiido That is not an issue. As long as `.catch()` is not reached the resource should exist, which is what `fetch()` portion of Answer attempts to achieve.

Comment: It could also be redirected.

Comment: @Kaiido Substituted `.status` for `.ok` to handle `404` code. Are you suggesting that `fetch()` portion of Answer is not reliable? Or could be improved?